# ubuntu installer does not initalize

Tags: system-installation

I have created a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu on it(with Rufus) for my new laptop that doesn't have an OS currently.
After inserting the bootable USB stick(boot option priority set to the USB), I restarted the laptop but I got to the Aptio setup - AMI screen again.
After inserting the USB stick in 2 other slots it still does not boot.
I have downloaded Ubuntu again and tried with that but it does not work either. Since the laptop has an UEFI-based system I tried to use "GPT" instead of "MBR" in the partition section but it was irrelevant as nothing happens as well.

Comment: You should [verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu). Then start over. But this time follow the official tutorial to [Install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you still need help, please reference the tutorial when asking. Keep in mind that as a prerequisite, you need to know how to use the features of your motherboard firmware. If you are having problems booting the USB, this is out of the realm of Ubuntu and you'll want to consult the motherboard documentation or support options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)